# Datagridview from mysql: Simple inventory stocks

Tags: vb.net, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to create a simple inventory stock and i'm having a hard time to get the remaining stocks base on the input and output from mysql.

What I really need is to subtract the total quantity of input.quantity - output.quantity where input.material is equal to output.material and if the total.quantity is below the safety stocks the datagridview will highlight the row.

```
conn = New MySqlConnection
 conn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=1234;database=inventory"
        Dim searchquery As String = "Select input.DeliveryDate as 'Delivery Date',input.Material, (sum(input.Quantity) - sum(output.Quantity)) as 'Remaining Stocks' where rawmaterialsinput.Material = output.Material, safetystandard.safetystocks from inventory.input, inventory.output, inventory.safetystandard"

        Dim commander As New MySqlCommand(searchquery, conn)
        Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(commander)

        inventorydata.Clear()

        adapter.Fill(inventorydata)

        inventoryDGV.DataSource = inventorydata
```

as of now this is the codes I'm trying but there's no hope. Please help

I need to have 4 column in datagridview with Delivery Date, Rawmaterials, Remaining Stocks, Safety Stocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
conn.Open()
        conn = New MySqlConnection
        conn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=SOUTHEAST;database=reportingsystem"
        Dim searchquery As String = "Select reportingsystem.rawmaterialswarehouseandrawmaterials.Rawmaterials as 'Raw Material', reportingsystem.rawmaterialswarehouseandrawmaterials.safetystocks as 'Safety Stocks', (select sum(reportingsystem.rawmaterialsinput.Quantity) - sum(reportingsystem.rawmaterialsoutput.Quantity) from reportingsystem.rawmaterialsinput, reportingsystem.rawmaterialsoutput where reportingsystem.rawmaterialsinput.RawMaterial = reportingsystem.rawmaterialswarehouseandrawmaterials.Rawmaterials ) as 'Remaining Stocks' from reportingsystem.rawmaterialswarehouseandrawmaterials" ' JOIN reportingsystem.rawmaterialsinput.RawMaterial ON reportingsystem.rawmaterialswarehouseandrawmaterials.Rawmaterials = reportingsystem.rawmaterialsinput.RawMaterial ORDER BY reportingsystem.rawmaterialswarehouseandrawmaterials.Rawmaterials"
        Dim commander As New MySqlCommand(searchquery, conn)
        Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(commander)

        monitoringdata.Clear()

        adapter.Fill(monitoringdata)

        MonitoringDGV.DataSource = monitoringdata 

conn.close()
```

in this code only 3 column is selected. Hope it's help